# OAuth token not retrieved with Uber API

Tags: oauth, uber-api

I am unable to retrieve the token in the OAuth process using the Uber API.
Here is my code:

```
require 'oauth2'
<%   client = OAuth2::Client.new('<client id>', '<client secret>', 
      :site => 'http://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code') %>
<%   token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', 
     :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:4567/callback', 
     :headers => {'Authorization' => "Token <token>"}) %>
```

Getting:

> OAuth2::Error - invalid_client:  {"error": "invalid_client"}:
>     /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/oauth2-1.0.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb:113:in
>   `request'

any idea ? I tried http/https , and code/token on the response type.

thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you had the wrong client id, check if it matches the one on your developer dashboard.